# Meaning of "Stir fecund"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I came across this phrase in literature, and I am not sure what it exactly means? Any help would be appreciated.

**Examples:**

D. H. Lawrence:

> That in the dark of the night ahead other days **stir fecund**, when we have lapsed from existence. One knows how utterly we shall lapse.

Han Suyin:

> Today is nearly gone, but other todays **stir fecund** in the word tomorrow, many other todays when this one has lapsed from existence

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your useful comments. I initially thought the phrase could be  read as "slowly preparing".

Comment: I really have only found two instances of this collocation of words, and it's exactly the two quotes you have given. The D. H. Lawrence one was written in "Studies in Classic American Literature" published in 1923. It was made while commentating Herman Melville's Moby Dick.  The second quote is from a woman Han Suyin in a love story novel published first in 1958. There being only two instances of this I can possibly find on Google, I have to assume the woman was a reincarnation of D. H. Lawrence, with the transference between corporeal beings maintaining Lawrence's idiolect intact.

Answer (score 1):

**other days stir fecund** [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=hf6vsKOP2UMC&lpg=PA124&ots=W0e8z1R626&dq=%22days%20stir%20fecund%22%20meaning&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q=%22days%20stir%20fecund%22%20meaning&f=false)

Our day is only a day.  Who knows how utterly we shall lapse.  Other days for other people to come will be fecund (happy, auspicious, fruitful).

**fecund**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68901?rskey=dbhWsR&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Of animals, the earth, etc.: Capable of producing offspring or
>   vegetable growth abundantly; prolific, fertile.

As in:

> Beneath it those who listen are aware of a faint, constant **stir**ring, a
>   whisper of green and eager things pushing themselves up from the
>   **fecund** soil. *Kelly, Eleanor Mercein*

and

> “In due season all that lives returns to dust, making the earth **fecund**
>   with life. Smell how the air tonight is pregnant with the flowers’
>   blooms and their bee-sought sweetness.” *Ophelia*

Answer (score 0):

*Fecund* means fertile or productive, so I would suggest *await, filled with possibility* as a similar meaning in both these cases.